# Which is the best way to work with 3rd party repositories in Odoo.sh?

Tags: odoo, odoo.sh

I got an Odoo 15 Enterprise running with the Odoo.sh platform.

When I add an OCA repository, I add it with the `Submodule` option, and this generates a OCA directory inside `src/user`. Which is the best way to update that code? If I go to `src/user/OCA/repository-name`, would doing a `git pull` there be ok?

Can anyone share their method? There is documentation on how to create your own modules, but not much about adding external repos and keep them updated.